# Using "extends" correctly to display inheritance in a Commandline argument

Tags: java, inheritance, command-line-arguments

The user is supposed to input a name, a last name, and the age in that order into the commandline, and it displays into a JoptionPlane. It then displays again with a Dr. in front of the arguments with the age increased by 1. However I am having trouble with my Public Earthling method, I keep getting the error

```
            "constructor Person in class Person cannot be applied to given types;
   public Earthling(String name1, String fn1, int age1){
                                                       ^
required: String,int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Expected Output (Dialog Boxes):

> Bill Johnson is 58 years old.
>
> Dr. Bill Johnson is 59 years old.

Heres my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Inheritance {

 /**
  * main method which begins the program
  * 
  * @param args is the people and age inputed
  */
  public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length <= 1) {
      System.out.println("Please enter a viable argument");
      System.exit(1); // ends the program
    } 

    Integer age = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    // Creates a person object
    Earthling familyname1 = new Earthling(args[0],args[1], age);

    //put here first so it displays without the Dr.
    String firstOutput = familyname1.toString();

    //calls the phd and birthday methods
    familyname1.phd();
    familyname1.birthday();

    String secondOutput = familyname1.toString();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, firstOutput);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, secondOutput);
  }
}

/* Stores the first name and age for a person */
class Person {
  protected String name;
  protected Integer age;

  /**
   * The Constructer, used for creating objects and initializing data
   * 
   * @param n1 is the Persons first name
   * @param a1 is the Persons age
   * 
   */
   public Person(String n1, int a1){
      name = n1;
      age = a1;
   }

   /* adds Dr. to the name */  
   public void phd() {
     name = "Dr. " + name;
   }

   /* adds 1 to the age */
   public void birthday() {
     age = age + 1;
   }

   /**
    * displays the data in each objects data field
    * 
    * @return The Persons name, family name and age
    */
   public String toString(){
     String output = name + " is " + age + " years old.";
     return output;
   }
 }

class Earthling extends Person {      
  protected String familyName;

  //Problem Here!
  public Earthling(String name1,String fn1, int age1){
    name = name1;
    familyName = fn1;
    age = age1;   
  }

  public String toString() {
    String output = name + familyName + " is " + age + " years old.";
    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to call super(name1, age1) as the first thing in Earthling's constructor.

Comment: Wow something so simple...still learning I guess, Thank you so much!

Comment: If it fixed your problem, please mark my answer below as the right one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `super(name1, age1)` as the first thing in Earthling's constructor.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html for an explanation of the `super` keyword in Java, and calling a superclass' constructur.